# tcl struct::matrix Warning: can't unset "colw(0)": no such element in array

Tags: tcl

I am trying to create a matrix using the following code:

```
package require struct::matrix
::struct::matrix GUI_TABLE
set NEW_LINE [list Data0 Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4]
GUI_TABLE add columns [llength $NEW_LINE]
GUI_TABLE add row $NEW_LINE
set NEW_LINE [list Data5 Data6 Data7 Data8 Data9]
GUI_TABLE add row $NEW_LINE
GUI_TABLE format 2chan
```

But the problem is that I am getting the following warnings every time I add a row:

```
//  Warning: can't unset "colw(0)": no such element in array
//  Warning: can't unset "colw(1)": no such element in array
//  Warning: can't unset "colw(2)": no such element in array
//  Warning: can't unset "colw(3)": no such element in array
//  Warning: can't unset "colw(4)": no such element in array
```

The only way to remove the warning that I could find is by executing the columnwidth command per column, which makes the code very slow if the matrix is big. I do not know why I am getting the warning, and if there is any better way to get rid of it? any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of struct::matrix do you have?

Comment: The version is 2.0.2

Comment: "works for me". Is there more to your code, or when you run this exact code you get these errors?

Comment: that is the exact code

Comment: I am executing this inside an EDA tool. I wonder if this is a side effect of something that is already loaded in the tool? Do you think namespace would help for that?

Comment: Iwas browsing through the source code, and "unset colw" appears all over the place. Many of those are `catch {unset colw($c)}` to prevent that exact error. I don't know what the differences between 2.0.2 and 2.0.3 are

Comment: My reading is that the EDA-bundled Tcl redefines `catch` and, therefore, reveals an otherwise intentionally swallowed error: the infamous `catch {unset x}` idiom. struct::matrix (and other places in struct) should be updated to use `unset -nocomplain x` (which would also mean for these warnings to go away).

Comment: I diff both versions 2.0.3 and 2.0.2 and all the places where colw is match

Comment: Thank you very much Mrcalvin and Glenn, I think both of you are right. So I found that there is a special catch command in the EDA tool that prevents errors/warnings to be printed. So I just add it into the add row command and the warnings disappeared, and the code is doing what I was expecting it to do. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeArturoCorso Glad that we could point you into a purposeful direction, you may want to https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mrcalvin and Glenn Jackman for the support and guidance to find the root cause of the problem. Here is the summary:
- The code for struc::matrix uses the catch command to get rid of the warnings/errors like the one I was having.
- The problem is that I was using an EDA tool that redefined the catch command and revealed the warning/error that was intentionally masked in the original code.
- The solution was to use a special catch command that the EDA tool provide, to mask the warnings when adding a new row. Like this:

```
package require struct::matrix
::struct::matrix GUI_TABLE
set NEW_LINE [list Data0 Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4]
GUI_TABLE add columns [llength $NEW_LINE]
catch_special { GUI_TABLE add row $NEW_LINE}
set NEW_LINE [list Data5 Data6 Data7 Data8 Data9]
catch_special { GUI_TABLE add row $NEW_LINE }
```

Comment: As a suggestion for improvement, maybe use `catch_special` more selectively to group more than one `add row command` ...